# Stanford NER - Extract Multi word entities

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

How can I tag collocations in Stanford NER? Currently it tags `Federal Reserve Bank of New York` as

```
<wi num="11" entity="ORGANIZATION">Federal</wi> <wi num="12" entity="ORGANIZATION">Reserve</wi> <wi num="13" entity="ORGANIZATION">Bank</wi> <wi num="14" entity="ORGANIZATION">of</wi> <wi num="15" entity="ORGANIZATION">New</wi> <wi num="16" entity="ORGANIZATION">York</wi>
```

I want it to be recognized as

```
<wi num="11" entity="ORGANIZATION">Federal Reserve Bank of New York</wi>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar is, yes.  If you give the flag

```
-outputFormat inlineXML
```

then you'll get:

```
<ORGANIZATION>Federal Reserve Bank of New York</ORGANIZATION>
```

(Note that this isn't really changing how Stanford NER works but just the formatting of output.  If you don't like any of the provided output formats, it is fairly simple to write your own.)

Comment: Can you please direct me on how to produce custom output formats?

Comment: You have to write code for this. The key method internally classifies lists of tokens: List<IN> classify(List<IN> document).  You can then print these tokens out however you want.  That's what the code in PlainTextDocumentReaderAndWriter which handles the standard styles does.

Comment: The classify method returns each word as a different token. I was unable to get the whole entity together.